# Defining an infinite sequence of Fibonacci numbers using list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension, fibonacci

How would I do this? It's part of an exercise in my lecture slides and the hints are to use the library functions `tail :: [a] -> [a]` and `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`. Also, the type of the function is `fibs :: [Integer]`

I know how list comprehension works, how to write a recursive Fibonacci function that takes in a value and am familiar with both the tail and zip functions - however, I just can't figure this one out and haven't been able to find an example online. Can anybody show me how its done?

Also out of curiosity, how are functions like this (that produce an infinite list) used in Haskell? If I write `fibs` (the function name) in the ghci command prompt for example will it continue to print the elements in the list until the end of time?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: for the example online part - I think you did not look to badly - it's the first one here: https://www.google.de/#q=haskell+fib :D

Answer (score 8):

Here's a hint.

Take the sequence of powers of two.

```
p2 = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...
```

`zip` it with itself

```
zip p2 p2 = [(1,1), (2,2), (4,4), ...]
```

Sum every pair in the list (this can be done using a list comprehension)

```
[2, 4, 8, ...
```

Prepend `1`:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, ...
```

So we got the `p2` list again. If you express all of this in Haskell, you end up with some code of the form

```
p2 = 1 : ... something involving p2 ...
```

which is a working program generating the powers of two.

Once you get this working, you can change it *slightly* and obtain Fibonacci as well.

For the last point: yes, printing `p2` will print the whole infinite sequence. You can print just a few elements using

```
take 10 p2
```

Comment: best *tutorial* I've seen so far! - this deserves a lot of upvotes :D - thanks man - I enjoyed it

Answer (score 3):

here is another one **chi** style (I hope you don't mind):

write the fibs:

```
fibs = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
```

write it again but shift one left:

```
fibs       = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
(??? fibs) = 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
```

add them:

```
fibs       = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
(??? fibs) = 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
--------------------
(+ em)     = 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...
```

looks familiar?

Now you only have to prepend something (again) and think about what *shift left*  means here (*hint* you mentioned it):

```
fibs       = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
(??? fibs) = 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...
--------------------
(+ em)     = 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...
=> fibs = ? : ((+ em) fibs (??? fibs))
```

Also summing up can be done nicely with `zipWith (+)`

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found using zip and tail:

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0:1:[x + y | (x,y) <- zip fibs (tail fibs)]
```

If you run fibs, it will keep printing until the computer runs out of memory and crashes. You can call functions that return infinite lists through `take` and `takeWhile` to return a finite list. Haskell uses lazy evaluation to make handling infinite data structures more efficient.

Example:

`take 10 fibs`

prints:

`[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]`